# broken paginator in bootstrap (laravel)

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4, paginator

I'm using Laravel and I downloaded a Bootswach template and replaced the one that Laravel brought. I know that surely this was not the procedure. The photo you see shows the pagination that has the previous and next buttons and those are fine. But the numbers and the images were wrong. Does anyone know what I could do to correct this? I don't know much css and I thought this wasn't going to happen since everything else was working fine. I appreciate if you can help me a little with this. Thank you very much

Add the class h-5 and w-5 that were not there.

> ```
> .h-5 {
>    height: 5% !important;    
>  }   
>  .w-5 {
>    width: 5% !important;   
>  }
> ```

looks better but not good

[image]

Comment: looks like the icons are embedded as svg and not having a `height` and `width` defined.

Comment: And it is. They are svg but at 3% it looks good. The problem is that the numbers should be between the previous and next buttons.

Comment: did you maybe installed a bs5 theme on bs4? Add the generated html of the block. maybe we can add styling to it.

Comment: Should I have done something like this or do I need to install something? I started a new project and the same thing happened.
public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrapFive();
    Paginator::useBootstrapFour();
}